# Удалить символы в начале и конце строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно с помощью регулярки образать все нули спереди, и один ноль в конце. Написал вот такую регулярку, но она работает не правильно `str.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/0+/, '')`. То есть мне нужно что бы к примеру из строки `0010400` мне возвращало `1040`

Comment: А у вас в строке всегда числа будут? Может легче сделать так `(+'0010400')/10`? Также вам просто надо поправить второй `replace`, а именно `'0010400'.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/0$/, '')`

Comment: `str.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/0$/, '')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

```js
console.log("0010400".replace(/^0+|0$/g, ''))
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Oqgyb9/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `0+` - один и более символов `0`
- `|` - или
- `0$` - 0 в конце строки.

Модификатор `g` находит все совпадения.